# Calendar api to display date alone

Tags: java

Here is my code to fetch and display date:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
        
public class Employee {
     private Calendar doj; 
     public Employee(Calendar date) {
     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.doj=date;
        }
        public Calendar getDoj() 
        { 
        return doj; 
        } 
        
     }
    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
    
public class TestEmployeeSort {
    
  /**
    * @param args
   */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Employee> coll = getEmployees();
        printList(coll);
    }
        public static List<Employee> getEmployees() 
        { 
            List<Employee> col = new ArrayList<Employee>();
              
            col.add(new Employee(Calendar.getInstance()));
            return col;
        } 
        private static void printList(List<Employee> list) { 
            System.out.println("Date_Of_Joining"); 
         
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { 
                Employee e = list.get(i); 
                System.out.println(e.getDoj()); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
Date_Of_Joining
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1291275522078,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2010,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=49,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_YEAR=336,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=13,MINUTE=8,SECOND=42,MILLISECOND=78,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

What I want to do is simply **to print the date alone**. Here, my output contains way too much data that I don't need. How should I change the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well personally I'd use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) (and its `LocalDate` class, if you really only want to maintain the date) rather than `java.util.Calendar`, but if you *do* want to use `Calendar`, you need a `SimpleDateFormat`.

java.util.Calendar sample:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Joda Time sample:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
        // Alternatively, use DateTimeFormat.mediumDate etc
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        System.out.println(formatter.print(today));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.text.DateFormat` instead of bare `Calendar`.

Answer (score 2):

use Caledar.getTime() that returns Date. Then use SimpleDateFormat to format it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://veyder-time.enblom.org It is a simple and powerful alternative to java.util.Calendar.

Comment: Good intellectual effort, but I think - have this sense when Joda time and new java 9 API exist on the market? The third, incompatible date api?